# Getting input with sc.nextInt() after Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())?

Tags: java

I have a Java program below. When I get integer value with sc.nextInt() after getting integer value with `Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine())`. I am getting numberformat Exception. Please help me out.

```
public class User {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int n=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
    int rank=sc.nextInt();
    String arr[]=new String[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i]=sc.nextLine();}
```

Can someone explain what was wrong with my code.

Comment: What is your input ?

Comment: Input: 6   2  . n value should be  6 and rank should be 2 .So that I can get 6 strings in loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int n=Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

When giving input `6 2` this line try to get convert `6 2` as integer since you use `.nextLine()`. That's why you get `Numberformat Exception`. You can use `n=sc.nextInt()` for taking input for n also. And take care the new line before get string input in loop.